# Sitecore caching and languages

Tags: caching, sitecore

I have a basic understanding of how Sitecore caching works including how all the different variations work.

But I am not how Sitecore handles languages during caching. Is each language version of a page treated as a different data source and is varybydata the answer then? If not, how can I safely apply caching to different language versions of a page?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sitecore includes the current language in the cache key, among other things, so every sublayout or rendering is treated as a different version in each language. So apply caching to different language versions should be no problem.

Comment: Do I need to use varybydata option with the caching?

Comment: No, it will auto-cache by language